# Как показать клавиатуру при открытии AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня открывается `AlertDialog`, в нём — `EditText` (`AutoCompleteTextView`). Нужно, чтобы сразу выскакивала клавиатура. А при обработке события хотелось бы её убрать.

Этот вопрос уже задавали, но ответы какие-то невнятные и в большинстве случаев вопрос не решён.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это чтобы клавиатура закрывалась в обработчик события вместо autotxt2 свой edittext:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(autotxt2.getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы клавиатура выпрыгнула при входе в активити, подойдёт этот код:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

(подсказали в группе ВК)